# Little locks inside form fields when using security roles other than System Administrator

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Currently we are working on an upgrade of the current system AX 2012 R1 to AX 2012 R3. After upgrading the code we started to test the security using the old security roles and discovered one problem. On one of our custom forms, when I try to add new record, the fields become gray with a little lock inside. I never saw this lock before and the role I'am using had enough rights to create and update records in the given tables before.

Maybe good to mention that this form has multiple data sources and it's look like something goes wrong while switching the focus from one data source to another.

I can't find anything about this little locks, normally when I didn't had the create/update rights for the given table the fields were just grayed out.

[image: Locks on the form fields]

Comment: Is one of the tables in the data source part of a table inheritance?

Comment: @FH-Inway No, there there are only two tables in the data source and they are both without inheritance.

Comment: Full compile, DB sync, AOS restart - I suppose everything has already been tried?

Comment: @10p Yes we have tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that table extension framework is used for some tables in form data sources. You can read more about it following next link:
http://daxonline.org/9-table-extension-framework.html

When table extension framework is used together with localization option (table properties CountryRegionCodes, CountryRegionContextField) and your legal entity is not within required country you will get such locks inside fields. And it is ok as there is no sense for example to fill in Ukrainian tax related fields in US company.